# Time/hour calculation in excel

Tags: excel

I’m so rusty on excel and I’m trying to work out a formula for this problem:

Shifts greater than 5 hours duration must take a 1 hour unpaid break.

I’m using for G5 =IF(G4>5:00:00,”1:00:00”,”0:00:00”)

G4 =shift duration, cell is formatted as [h]:mm

Once I get this to work I then add G4 and G5 and to get the shift finish time.

It sounds so simple but it’s driving me crazy!!!  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores time field internally as numbers, where 1 is a complete day (which is 24 hours).

If G4 has the value "06:30" (a time ), Then a formula in G5 like this:
`=G4*24`, will give you the numeric value `6.5`.

You formula to check for more than 5 hours can be:
`IF(G4*24>5,"01:00:00","00:00:00")`

But this will return a text (i.e.:"01:00:00"). This can be solved by adding the function `TIMEVALUE()`

```
=TIMEVALUE(IF(G4*24>5,"01:00:00","00:00:00"))
```

EDIT:
Another way can be:

```
=IF(G4>TIME(5,0,0),"01:00:00","00:00:00")
```

Comment: @MelissaB You should then accept the answer (tick mark it). When you tick it then we will know that your problem is solved.